# Installing VirtualBox Guest Additions on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, dpkg

I was trying to install virtualbox-guess-additions-iso, and got the following error:

```
sudo aptitude install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso

The following NEW packages will be installed:
libgsoap1{a} virtualbox{a} virtualbox-dkms{a} virtualbox-guest-additions-iso  
virtualbox-qt{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/64.0 MB of archives. After unpacking 121 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
virtualbox-4.3 : Conflicts: virtualbox but 4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.5 is to be  
installed.
              Conflicts: virtualbox-guest-additions-iso but 4.1.12-1 is to be 
installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
   Remove the following packages:
1)     virtualbox-4.3     


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   libgsoap1{a} virtualbox{a} virtualbox-dkms{a} virtualbox-guest-additions-iso   
   virtualbox-qt{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
   virtualbox-4.3{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/64.0 MB of archives. After unpacking 33.0 MB will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
(Reading database ... 484051 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox-4.3 ...
dpkg: error processing virtualbox-4.3 (--remove):
  subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Errors were encountered   
while processing:
  virtualbox-4.3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Guest Additions in VirtualBox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox)

Comment: [Please don't cross post.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118587/subprocess-installed-pre-removal-script-returned-error-exit-status-1)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're running VirtualBox 4.3 but the PPA for VirtualBox in the Ubuntu repositories is pulling an older version 4.1.12.

If you want to install the virtual box guest additions for the proper version of VirtualBox you're running I'd suggest [using the Virtual Box Manager menu option](http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-ubuntu/).

Comment: There's no such option under Devices menu, I only have "Insert Guest Addition CD image" instead of "Install Guest Additions"

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Click that option and it will automatically load the CD image for the Guest Additions, which should then prompt you to install.

Comment: I do not have .iso on my machine, that's why I was trying to install it from the repo.